# Color picker: unsigned char pixelData incompatible to void

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile

I try to insert this old project: http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/rgba-color-information-of-cgpoint.828391/ in my new project based on IOS 8.3 but in this function

```
- (void)createCGContextWithImage:(UIImage*)image
{
CGImageRef imageRef = [image CGImage];
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
NSUInteger imageRefHeight = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

imageRefWidth = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
pixelData = malloc(imageRefWidth * imageRefHeight * 4);

NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
NSUInteger bytesPerRow = (bytesPerPixel * imageRefWidth);
NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixelData, imageRefWidth, imageRefHeight, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageRefWidth, imageRefHeight), imageRef);
CGContextRelease(context);

//CGBitmapContextGetData() }
```

I get the error:

```
Assigning to "unsigned char" from incompatible type void.
```

Comment: How are you calling this "createCGContextWithImage"   method.             For example: [self createCGContextWithImage:yourImageName]?

Comment: In viewDidLoad: UIImage *colorWheelImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
    self.pictureView.image = colorWheelImage;
    [self createCGContextWithImage:colorWheelImage];